# Adding header to an ascii catalogue

Tags: bash, awk, sed, header

I would like to add a header to an `ascii` file using `bash script`. What is the shortest way to do it without making *temporary* text file?

Comment: @anubhava I know `sed` can be used but I don't know how the command line should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way

```
sed '1 i\Header' FileName
```

**Example:**

```
seq 5 | sed '1 i\\tHeader'
```

**Output:**

```
    Header
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this won't work in all versions of sed. In some versions you need to add a newline after the `i\ `. This is the [behaviour defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) so should be usable everywhere.

Comment: so use `--posix` on GNU sed and add a new line

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `BEGIN` block in awk to print some output before the file is processed:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "header text"}1' input.txt > output.txt
```

A newline will be appended after the header string. If this is undesired, you can use `printf` instead. The `1` at the end is a shorthand, which means that all the lines in the file are printed.

In order to overwrite the original file, you can just use a temporary file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "header text"}1' input.txt > tmp && mv tmp input.txt
```